# How can we write Jest test cases for TextInput in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm relatively new to Jest and testing in general. I have a component with a text input element:

Here is my code snippet

```
<TextInput
             testID="messageText"
             ref={inputRef}
             value={title}
             onChangeText={(text) => {
               setTitle(text)
             }}
           />
```

Every time I am getting the error

*Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 2 found instead.*

Here is my code --

```
  const navigation = jest.fn()
  const onChange = jest.fn();

   const props = {
    navigation: {
      state: {
        params: {
          postType: 'text'
        }
      }
    },
  }
 
  let wrapper
  const event = {
    target: {
      value: 'This is just for test'
    }
  }
  it('renders', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<NewFeedComponent {...props} />)
    wrapper.find('Text').simulate('change', event)
    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('This is just for test');
  })
})
```

Comment: I would suggest to read some docs first [that](https://reactnative.dev/docs/testing-overview) . No one is going to write any code if you haven't tried yourself first.  Better question would be I stuck here what can I do. Community help when you tried first by yourself

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for not making my problem statement more clear. I have updated it @ShubhamVerma

Comment: Now that's much better :clap:. Is your `NewFeedComponent ` has any async part? and have you configured jest and enzyme in code correctly?

Comment: No, there is no async part in it, and yes everything is configured

Comment: The error indicating that the 'wrapper' is undefined.  Then how come this line passed - wrapper.setState({ params: params }). Can you console and check the 'wrapper' ?

Comment: @SarunUK There was some problem before. I have updated my problem statement

Comment: there might be more than one 'Text' node. So you have to select the appropriate node based on your use case. wrapper.find('Text').at(index).simulate()

Comment: Not working, when I log wrapper it is returning -- ShallowWrapper {}

Comment: use wrapper.debug(). it will give more information. And Is there any reason, you are using 'Text'  instead of 'TextInput' ?

Answer (score -1):

I created one sandbox so that you can understand more context. Just go through this sandbox(dont forget to run test runner to see actually test works):

code:

> App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <input
      type={props.type}
      value={value}
      name="email"
      className="basic-input"
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

> App.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import { mount, shallow, configure } from "enzyme";

import App from "./App";
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("basic input component", () => {
  it("should renders without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
  });

  it("should render a placeholder", () => {
    const placeholder_text = "type anything here";
    const wrapper = shallow(<App placeholder={placeholder_text} />);
    expect(wrapper.prop("placeholder")).toEqual(placeholder_text);
  });

  it("should render a correct type", () => {
    const type = "password";
    const wrapper = shallow(<App type={type} />);
    expect(wrapper.prop("type")).toEqual(type);
  });

  it("should change the state after change the input value", () => {
    const newValue = "testing component";
    const wrapper = mount(<App value="" type="text" />);
    // const input = wrapper.find('input[type="text"]');
    wrapper
      .find('input[name="email"]')
      .simulate("change", { target: { value: newValue } });

    expect(wrapper.find('input[name="email"]').prop("value")).toEqual(newValue);
  });
});
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-jest-enzyme-jn3ld?file=/src/App.js:0-360

Comment: Not working. Getting error with mount and shallow is returning a blank object

Comment: what error coming. Did you check sandbox demo? Its running fine there

Comment: OP is asking about react-native and jest, you are using react and enzyme.